# Spring Boot always throws 403 and CORS policy error

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vuejs3

I'm relative new to Spring Boot and VueJS. I'm developing an web application with Vue frontend and Spring Boot backend with a Google login via Google SDK.
The frontend and backend  work just fine but the communication between both isn't working. When I try to make a GET call to the backend via the BackendService.js I get the following error message in the browsers console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'BACKEND_URL/match/231' from origin 'FRONTEND_URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET BACKEND_URL/match/231 net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)

Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Following my Spring SecurityConfig.java classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests();
        CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
        cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("FRONTEND_URL"));
        cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", cors);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MatchMaker_BE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MatchMaker_BE</name>
    <description>MatchMaker_BE</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my BackendService.js from the Vue frontend

```
import axios from "axios";

const BACKEND_BASE_URL = "BACKEND_URL"
//const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
//const headers = {Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken};

class BackendService{
    getMatch(matchId){
        console.log("Übermittelt match ID: " + matchId);
        const requestURI = BACKEND_BASE_URL + "/match/" + matchId;
        console.log("Übermittelt an: " + requestURI);
        return axios.get(requestURI/*, {headers: headers}*/);
    }
}

export default new BackendService()
```

I also tried to use another WebConfig.java class but that didn't change anything

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        // Erlaube Anfragen von allen Ursprüngen
        config.addAllowedOrigin("FRONTEND_URL");

        // Erlaube bestimmte HTTP-Methoden (GET, POST, etc.)
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");

        // Erlaube bestimmte HTTP-Header
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

I already tried different variations in my `SecurityConfig`. The class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` doesn't work with my Java version I think.

Also I thought about using the info I get from the Google SDK as a header-token for the backend call but I don't know how to verify the token in the backend when I can't reach it at all.

Comment: Delete `http.cors().disable();`

Instead, write `http.cors();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
The issue was that the /login route wasn't defined within my CORS configuration. I added a loginForm and login parameter to my webConfig file and changed the Google SSO Login from the vanilla SDK to Firebase which works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding FilterRegistrationBean bean instead of CorsFilter

@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean customCorsFilter() {

```
UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
    new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
  config.setAllowCredentials(false);
  config.addAllowedOrigin(this.allowedOrigins);
  config.addAllowedHeader("*");
  config.addAllowedMethod("*");
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean =
    new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
return bean;
```

}

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but I still get the 403...

Comment: How are giving AllowedOrigin it should be ip or domain.
Also need try adding the bean to SecurityConfig

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request).
Try something like

```
  http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the snippet which I slightly customized and fit into my SecurityConfig.java but I still get the 403.
Thats how I fitted it:
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                .requestMatchers("*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(optionsMatcher()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
@Bean
    public RequestMatcher optionsMatcher() {
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name());
    }